# Spring Boot upgrade from 2.2.x to 2.4.x: @Test's no longer have access to active profile via @activatedProperties@ in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, properties

I have just upgraded a project from Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE to 2.4.5. I have unit tests that rely on the setting of the active Spring profile.

application properties:

`spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@`

The tests now fail because the substitution is no longer happening correctly in the test application context.

A failing test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.profiles.active=test"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Main.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"myco"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class GenericClientTest {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile; // <-- NOW gets set to "@activatedProperties@" instead of "test"

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        if (activeProfile.equals("test")) {
            doImportantStuff();  // <-- NO LONGER make it to here
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testNumberOne() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

This is the test dependency in the pom.xml, which did not change:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I know 2.4.x changes property file handling, but if the profile substitution via @activatedProperties@ works still in the running context, why does it no longer work for `@Test`'s?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, setting the `spring.profiles.active` via the `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation is considered to be an implementation detail and is not reliable. As seen in [this discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21631#issuecomment-666765044) and [here also](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19788), Spring Boot upgrades from v2.2.x to 2.3.x and 2.3.x to 2.4.x exposed this issue.

The best practice is to explicitly set the profile in `@SpringBootTest`:

```
  @SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.profiles.active=test"})
```

and this worked for me. For upgrades to 2.4.x specifically, it was suggested to create a test-specific application.properties in a multi-document `.properties` file, which I will try also.